# Ruby on Rails Error "Validation failed: Item can't be blank, category4 can't be blank, category1 can't be blank"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation, input

```
  def create
    item = current_administrator.items.build(params[:category1])
    item.created_at = Time.now
    item.save!
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

The code will not do `item.save!` because it thinks that the categories in the form are blank, but they have been completed.

```
Validation failed: Item can't be blank, Category4 can't be blank, Category1 can't be blank
```

The form:

```
<%= form_for VerbRegular.new do |f| %>
  <div id="add_verb_container">
    <%= f.text_field :category1 %>
    <%= f.text_field :category2 %>
    <%= f.text_field :category3 %>
    <%= f.check_box :type %>
    <%= f.text_field :category4 %>
    <%= f.text_field :comment %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Add to list" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post the code from your model? Also, there are some syntax errors in the controller code you've posted (line 3 should be item I think), are you sure that's what you've got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`build(params[:category1])?` just passing *category1*? probably you need something more like `build(params[:verb_regular])`

Comment: Now I only get `Validation failed: Item can't be blank`